# Convert BYTES to INT

Tags: google-bigquery, bit-manipulation

How would I convert a `BYTES` value into `INT`? For example, the bitwise operations, `|`, `^`, `&`, `>>`, `<<` are defined on both `BYTES` and `INT`, and so the following both work:

```
SELECT 97   << 0;
SELECT b'a' << 0;
```

Is there a way to convert a `BYTES` value into `INT`, for example, I believe `b'a` would evaluate to `97` if a little-endian number `UINT32`, I think.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
SELECT CAST(b'a' AS INT) << 0;
```

To get the decimal value `97` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other ways, but

```sql
SELECT TO_CODE_POINTS(b'a')[OFFSET(0)] << 0;

+-----+
| f0_ |
+-----+
|  97 |
+-----+
```